# How can I open an auction at a scheduled time automatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, scheduled-tasks

I'm building a simple Rails auction website.

My auctions have a set `opening_time` attribute and I'd like to have the system open them automatically when they're supposed to.

```
@auction.update_column(:status, 'open')
```

I could 'ping' the backend every second to open all 'needing to open' auctions, but this is really wasteful and seems like a roundabout way to accomplish my goal.

This application is hosted on Heroku - what do I need to accomplish this in Ruby on Rails?

Comment: Have "open" be derived from `start_at < now < min(closed_at, end_at)`. Then there is no need to make it open or closed, except for time passing.

Comment: I'm using Pusher with websockets, so something has to let the clients know so I can run some clientside JS. Am I missing something?

Comment: I would still keep that separate from updating the model (eg update_column) however the clients poll or are pushed updates.

Comment: "are pushed updates." That's the relevant bit of the question ;) - How can I fire off the 'push' at the right time?

Comment: Clients are browser/JavaScript.. or?

Comment: @user2864740 browser javascript

Comment: What causes the client to need new information? If using the rules presented in my first comment, given this information at the start would allow the client to for, representation purposes, display the "auction is opening/open" status (even with it's own awesome countdown code). But consider this: how does the client get *other* information such as "current number of/highest bids"? The client receiving new updates, which is *a different process* than the server updating, happens for many different data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `clockwork` gem, written to be a `cron` replacement:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduled-jobs-custom-clock-processes

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clock-processes-ruby

https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork

EDIT: I also like user2864740's suggestion; if that were an answer, I'd +1 it too.